# Parent component unnecessarily re-renders all children when passing a ref to child nodes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-forwardref, react-memo

I have the following use-case:

- Component **A** is a memoized (`React.memo`) component whose ref is being forwarded (`React.forwardRef`).
- Component **B** is a memoized component (`React.memo`) that renders **multiple A components**, by mapping over a list.

When component **B**'s list gets a new element, **all children A components** are re-rendered, when they shouldn't.

**Code**

```
type Handle = {
  jump: () => void;
};

const Y = React.memo(
  React.forwardRef<Handle, { entry: number }>((props, ref) => {
    console.log("render");
    React.useImperativeHandle(
      ref,
      () => ({
        jump: () => {
          console.log("test");
        },
      }),
      []
    );

    return <div>{props.entry}</div>;
  })
);

const X: React.FC = React.memo(() => {
  const nodes = React.useRef<{ [key: string]: Handle }>({});
  const [array, setArray] = React.useState([1, 2, 3]);

  const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    setArray(array.concat(4));
  }, [array]);

  const jumpToNode = React.useCallback(() => {
    nodes.current["1"]?.jump();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>add new</button>
      <button onClick={jumpToNode}>jump to first node</button>
      {array.map((e) => (
        <Y
          ref={(no: Handle) => { // <---- CULPRIT
             nodes.current[e.toString()] = no;
          }}
          entry={e}
          key={e}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
});
```

**Investigation**

When commenting out the **ref** that's being passed down to each component **A**, only the new incoming node gets rendered, while all other nodes do not re-render.

I created a simple codesandbox example in https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-typescript-forked-jckhqq?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx, that showcases the issue mentioned above. With the console open:

- All nodes will initially be rendered once
- Click the "add new" button
- You will see only a single "render" console, coming from the new node

If the `ref` is then commented in, every time the "add new" button is clicked, all nodes are re-rendered.

I don't understand why that is happening and what one can do to avoid these unnecessary re-renderings. Our specific use-case is a computationally expensive component and every single render counts.

React version: **16.9.0**

Comment: It happens because the ```ref``` function changes its reference on each render. Seems like ```memo``` compares it with the previous ref and since they are always different, it decides to rerender. Not sure what can be the best solution for this, but if you can memoize the ref value, it can solve your problem. You can use ```useCallback```, but since it is used inside array, you have to create new component that returns ```Y``` and passes its ```ref``` with ```useCallback```. Or you can move that ref logic inside the children.

Comment: @OktayYuzcan creating a callback for the ref assignment doesn't seem to solve the issue. All children are still re-rendered

Comment: @OktayYuzcan could you share an example of what you meant with `You can use useCallback, but since it is used inside array, you have to create new component that returns Y and passes its ref with useCallback`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ref` causes `React.memo` to consider `props` as changed, and the component is re-rendered. The `memo` accepts a [custom comparison function](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-typescript-forked-nc7fjl?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00083b6kfo0af63a%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00043b6kq1e7rcnw%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00053b6kcjk8dudz%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00073b6k6v5u8prp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqxlzjvq00043b6kq1e7rcnw%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00033b6kc43jwr8t%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A38%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A26%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A38%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A26%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00043b6kq1e7rcnw%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00033b6kc43jwr8t%2522%257D%252C%2522clqxlzjvq00073b6k6v5u8prp%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00063b6kegoyda61%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00073b6k6v5u8prp%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00063b6kegoyda61%2522%257D%252C%2522clqxlzjvq00053b6kcjk8dudz%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00053b6kcjk8dudz%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) (`arePropsEqual`) to check if the props have changed as a 2nd parameter, and you can use it to ignore certain parameters when checking for equality. However, although `React.memo` doesn't ignore the `ref`, the `ref` is compared regardless of the result of `arePropsEqual`.

So the simple solution, in my opinion, is to avoid using `refForwarding` in this case, passing the `ref` as a normal parameter (`jumpRef` in the example), and ignoring it in the `React.memo` ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-typescript-forked-nc7fjl?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00083b6kfo0af63a%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00043b6kq1e7rcnw%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00053b6kcjk8dudz%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00073b6k6v5u8prp%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqxlzjvq00043b6kq1e7rcnw%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00033b6kc43jwr8t%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A38%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A26%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A38%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A26%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FApp.tsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00043b6kq1e7rcnw%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00033b6kc43jwr8t%2522%257D%252C%2522clqxlzjvq00073b6k6v5u8prp%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00063b6kegoyda61%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00073b6k6v5u8prp%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00063b6kegoyda61%2522%257D%252C%2522clqxlzjvq00053b6kcjk8dudz%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqxlzjvq00053b6kcjk8dudz%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)):

```
const X: React.FC = React.memo(() => {
  const nodes = React.useRef<{ [key: string]: Handle }>({});
  const [array, setArray] = React.useState([1, 2, 3]);

  const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    setArray((arr) => arr.concat(arr.length + 1));
  }, []);

  const jumpToNode = React.useCallback(() => {
    nodes.current["1"]?.jump();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>add new</button>
      <button onClick={jumpToNode}>jump to first node</button>
      {array.map((e) => (
        <Y
          jumpRef={(no: Handle) => {
            nodes.current[e.toString()] = no;
          }}
          entry={e}
          key={e}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
});

type JumpRef = (no: Handle) => void;
type Props = {
  entry: number;
  jumpRef: JumpRef; // instead of normal ref
};

const Y = React.memo(
  ({ entry, jumpRef }: Props) => {
    console.log("render");
    React.useImperativeHandle(
      jumpRef,
      () => ({
        jump: () => {
          console.log("test");
        },
      }),
      []
    );

    return <div>{entry}</div>;
  },
  // only check if entry changed for example
  (oldProps, newProps) => oldProps.entry === newProps.entry
);
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I still don't understand though why `React.memo` would compare the ref.